# How to modify rngd's default command line?

Tags: linux, command-line, services

I need to perform the following...

> `rngd`'s default command line should be modified to add
>   `--no-tpm=1`

`rngd` is a daemon that feeds data from a random number generator to the kernel's random number entropy pool, after first checking the data to ensure that it is properly random.

How do I modify its command line to add `--no-tpm=1`? What file do I need to modify or what command should I run to accomplish the task?

P.S. I need to do this to fix [this bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=921122) on my system.

Thank you.

Comment: What distribution are you using?  More exactly: How is `rngd` started on your system, which kind of `init` system is used (`upstart`, `systemd`, SysV-`init`, …)?

Comment: Redhat and systemd.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. The file I needed to modify is this one

```
/usr/lib/systemd/system/rngd.service
```

I modified one of the lines like so

```
ExecStart=/sbin/rngd -f --no-tpm=1
```